# Classifying the Hessian Matrix of a Morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Consider a morphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with image $\phi(\mathbf{x})$, which is continuously differentiable. Note that $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a monoid under multiplication and we define $\phi$ to be an multiplicative map. Could algebraic properties imply that the hessian of $\phi$ at $\mathbf{x}$, denoted $\mathbf{H}_{i,j}(\phi,\mathbf{x})$, is negative semidefinite (all eigenvalues are $\leq 0$)? For example, if $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, the Jacobian determinant of the regular map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonzero constant.

If useful, there is a principle minor test, similar to Sylvestor's criterion, for negative semidefinite matrices [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170107084552/http://prussing.ae.illinois.edu/semidef.pdf).

Comment: First, it is incorrect to say that the Jacobian determinant of the regular map $\varphi$ is zero iff $\varphi$ is an isomorphism (try the identity map). When you say that $\phi$ is a morphism, what do you mean and why do you feel it is important to point out that $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ is a monoid under multiplication and addition?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Addressing the first point, that was a typo which has been fixed (I meant nonzero instead of zero and, from what I know, the iff case has not been proven yet). By morphism, I mean a structure-preserving map between two mathematical structures of the same type (i.e. from category theory). When I pointed out that $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a monoid, I just wanted to refer to which structure I had in mind. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm well aware of what a morphism is, I'm asking what type of morphism you're using here - it's not clear to me what category you want to work in. Do you mean an additive map? a multiplicative map? a continuous map? some combination, or something else? In principal, it's possible that a monoid automorphism of $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ under addition may not even be continuous so your question about the Hessian may not even make sense.

Comment: Oh, I see. Firstly, $\phi$ is continuously differentiable. Also, I think that preserving addition is more relevant in my case, since $\phi(\mathbf{0})=0$, and so let's define $\phi$ to be an additive map. I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma**. If $\phi:\Bbb R_{\geq 0}^n\to\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ is continuous and additive, then it is linear.

*Proof*. For any nonnegative integer $n$, $\phi(nx)=\phi((n-1)x+x)=\phi((n-1)x)+\phi(x)=\cdots = n\phi(x)$, so for any nonnegative rational $\frac{a}{b}$ we get that $\phi(\frac{a}{b}x)=\frac{a}{b}\phi(x)$ and by continuity we see that $\phi(tx)=t\phi(x)$ for any $t\in\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$. $\blacksquare$

The Hessian is therefore zero.

Comment: Thank you for this and you correctly answered the current version of my question. However, it is not quite what I'm looking for (my fault not yours). I was looking through examples of concave functions (in particular neoclassical production functions) yesterday and realised that multiplication is preserved rather than addition. Obviously, $\phi(\mathbf{0})=0$ does not imply that $\phi$ is an additive map. So, could a result be shown for multiplicative maps (and I expect that this would be non-trivial)?

Comment: Also, is there a reason why $\phi$ maps from $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$ to itself when $\phi:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$? The automorphism I provided in my question was just meant for to illustrate what I meant by algebraic properties through a well known theorem (e.g. homomorphism, isomorphism, etc.).

Comment: 1) How about the following: a continuous function out of $\Bbb R^n_{\geq0}$ is determined by its values on $\Bbb R^n_{>0}$, so use $\log$ to turn your multiplicative function there in to an additive function. Repeat the above proof. 2) The reason was that I made a typo.

Comment: Suppose $\phi(K,A,L)=K^{\alpha}(AL)^{1-\alpha}$ (the Solow-Swan production function). This is clearly multiplicative, since $\phi(K_1 K_2, A_1 A_2, L_1 L_2)=\phi(K_1,A_1,L_1)\phi(K_2,A_2,L_2)$. The logarithm of $\phi$ is $\alpha \ln K + (1-\alpha)\ln(AL)$. This is generally not additive. Have I misinterpreted?

Comment: That is additive, once you realize the variables are $\ln K$, $\ln A$, and $\ln L$. (Apply log to *both sides*.) This won't necessarily show the Hessian is zero, but it will put the map in to a form which is easy to analyze.

Comment: How can knowing the Hessian of $\ln \phi$ (considering each variable as $\ln x_i$) be used to make a statement about the hessian of the original map $\phi$?